# How to create an URL based on a string containing scheme+host+port

Tags: dart

I have a string containing the scheme+host+port. For example: `http://192.120.123.1:4000` where the scheme is `http` , the host is  `192.120.123.1` and the port is `4000`

Other example are:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/

http:localhost

http://google.com:4000
```

How to create an instance of the [Uri](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Uri-class.html) class of Dart based on that string ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Uri.parse](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Uri/parse.html) to parse a `String` as Uri, or initialize the `Uri` using the the named parameters such as:

```
Uri(scheme: 'https', host: 'google.com', port: 4000);
```